# Windows 7 sp1 stuck checking for updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I am asking here because I have tried everything I can and it wont fix. I restored to different restore points, returned to factory three times, and ran the auto fix utilities.

It updated Saturday but the updates failed and since then it hangs on checking for updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when upgrading from 7 to 10. It turned out that the downloads had corrupted. You have to manually remove the downloaded files and rerun the update check. The path to check is:

```
X:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
```

Where `X:\` is your system drive. See this forum [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/10808-windows-7-corrupted-windows-update-file-where-delete.html) for reference.

If you have any additional error messages please update your question with them.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a new WindowsUpdate Client Update to fix the slow Update searching/Installation.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

Try this new Update and look if it speeds up the installation of Updates.